# Auto populate user field values by URl hacking

Tags: urlhacking

Is it possible to fetch the user field values by using URL Hacking?

```
https://domain.cs69.my.salesforce.com/a0s/e?retURL=%2Fa0s%2Fo&RecordType=012o0000123pEji&00No0000005nae4={$User.Phone}
```

I am trying to auto-populate user phone number directly into one of the custom object field.
**I am sure we can do this Using URL hack but not sure what is wrong here?**

Comment: From where you are redirecting this link ?

Comment: From JavaScript button

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing here ? Is it not populating ? Did you checked this 00No0000005nae4 is correct?

Comment: Are you loading a new page when you hit this javascript button ?

Comment: yes , i am opening new page after clicking the JavaScript button,

Comment: So from JavaScript you are passing user phone number correct ? That parameter  id is correct ?

Comment: Parameter is correct but values is not coming in phone {$User.Phone}

Answer (score 0):

You can get URL parameters using

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParamName')`

Here is the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm

Comment: This is not an Apex application. The question is about URL hacking in a JavaScript button.